# Git mergetool using TortoiseSvn and not TortoiseGit on windows

Tags: git, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

At the moment whenever I use the git mergetool, it is defaulting the TortoiseSvn mergetool.

Is there a way to configure the git mergetool to use TortoiseGit instead?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a path issue (the path for `TortoiseSVN/bin` coming first, before `TortoiseGit/bin`).

But you could define explicitly the `mergetool` you want with a config like:

```
git config merge.tool tortoise
git config mergetool.tortoise.cmd "c:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseMerge.exe" \
   /base:"$BASE" /theirs:"$REMOTE" /mine:"$LOCAL" /merged:"$MERGED"
```